# Atom typescript tsconfig and npm configuration

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I have a new Typescript project. It's being developed using Atom with the atom-typescript package. In order to disable automatic typescript compilation on save it was necessary to include a tsconfig.json file at the root of the project.

My project is separated into multiple files. At the top of each file I'm being sure to include references to other files it needs. So that at compile time the files are included in the outputted file.

However before compilation I'm not receiving any warnings that references are missing.

For example:

Animal.ts

```
class Animal {
}
```

Horse.ts

```
class Horse extends Animal {
}
```

When I compile Horse.ts I receive warnings that Animal doesn't exist. When I include a reference everything works as it should.

Horse.ts

```
/// <reference path="./Animal"/>
class Horse extends Animal {
}
```

I'd like Atom to tell me that reference is missing. When I remove tsconfig, every time I save any file it compiles. If I include "files": ["Horse.ts"] in tsconfig then any time I save Animal.ts, it compiles. I'd like to avoid any auto compilation while still receiving warnings about missing references.

Comment: when you add a "tsconfig" file, the whole directory becomes a single project. what's the content of your config file?

Comment: It's just "compileOnSave": false, as all I want is for Atom to stop compiling. But this is causing Atom to assume every file has access to everything from every other file in the directory. Full content: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}

Comment: I suggest you remove your file and open an issue in atom-typescript repo. Or just switch to another IDE (VSCode is a very good choice)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The simplest solution was to switch to visual studio code, it is a good editor. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `tsconfig.json` file, the whole directory becomes a single project. Typescript will compile it as a project instead of compiling each file individually.

You’ll have to remove that file. Either switch to another editor or contact the authors of *atom-typescript* and let them know about this.